# What's the missing number related to primes?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

I would like to draw your attention to this mathematical sequence related to prime numbers I've created and ask what the missing number is.

2, 5, 27, 182, 2310, 27200, ______, 8998400, 223092870, 6104948064, 200560490130, 7080748646400...

It is an even six-digit number.

Comment: Sorry is the sequence itself related to primes or just the missing number. This is unclear from the wording. Also ‘related to primes’ isn’t really a helpful hint if you mean it to be as every number could be seen a being related to primes either by being one itself or composed of them.

Comment: These are either equal or pretty close to the sequence of primorial numbers. With the hint given, I think that might be relevant, but I don’t know how yet

Comment: I'm sorry. The whole sequence is related to the prime numbers and every number of the sequence is related to them not only in the trivial way of "being composed of them". It is relevant that the sequence is close to primorial numbers.

Comment: related is still a very vague term. prime decomposition introduces seemingly random prime factors at times even with some primorials.